# Change memory of WebODM using Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ram, wsl-2

I would like to change RAM memory of Docker via WSL2 in order to run WebODM. From what I have read, I just need to change the memory value from a .wslconfig file BUT every time I do this, nothing happens. Docker is currently running 7GB and 8 Cores and I want to increase it to 12 GB since Im using my PC to only run that program. Can anyone tell me what step Im missing? please see the images attached to see what I have on my end. Also, I saw that I needed to add ubuntu but still don`t know how to properly implement it to my issue (not an expert on this topic).

Thanks[image: current docker memory]
[image: general settings]
[image: memory]
[image: resources]
[image: wslconfig file]
[image: features]